# How to get -1 to not be calculated in the program

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FactMore {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=1;

        int factorial = factorial(n);   

        while (n >= 1) {
            System.out.print("Enter a non-negative integer (-1 to quit) : ");
            n = keyboard.nextInt();
            factorial = factorial(n);
            System.out.println(n + "! = " + factorial);}

        if (n == 0) {
            System.out.print(n = 1); }
        if (n == -1) {
            System.out.print("Goodbye!"); }

    }

    public static int factorial(int n) {

        int factorial = 1;

        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            factorial = factorial * i; }

        return factorial;
        }
}
```

I am writing a program that repeatedly calculates the factorial of the imputed number, and it will do so until -1 is typed in. How do I get the program to not print -1! = 1 when I am trying to stop the program? Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Add a `break` statement and move `n == -1` check before the line that prints the factorial

Comment: Just check `n` and then `break` if it's `-1` after you read it

Comment: How should the program behave if another negative integer than `-1` is input? Ask again?

Comment: Putting your right braces at the end of lines makes your code much harder to follow.

Answer (score 3):

Your program is doing this right now:

1. Read number
2. Calculate factorial
3. Evaluate for exit

What you want:

1. Read number
2. Evaluate for exit
3. Calculate factorial

So for this, move the `if` statements inside the `while` loop and add a `break` inside the `-1` condition, you'll also need `else` statements, and I'd also move the evaluation for `n == 0` to the factorial calculation method

**And for the sake of readability move the closing curly braces to their own line!**

```
while (n >= 1) {
    System.out.print("Enter a non-negative integer (-1 to quit) : ");
    n = keyboard.nextInt(); //Read
    if (n == 0) { //Evaluate
        System.out.print(1); //Remove (n = 1) as suggested by @Aaron in the comments below, it is weird and may cause strange issues in larger programs
    } else if (n == -1) { //Evaluate
        System.out.print("Goodbye!");
        break; //Exit
    } else { //Calculate
        factorial = factorial(n);
        System.out.println(n + "! = " + factorial);
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.print(n = 1);` is even worse than the end-of-line closing brackets IMO, in the context of your answer I suggest changing it to `System.out.print(1);` but OP should remove that branch and handle the `x=0` case inside the `factorial` function.

Comment: Oh, nice catch, I noticed it earlier but forgot to mention it @Aaron :) check the edit ^^ and yeah I agree it should be inside the `factorial` method as I said in the explanation above the code

Comment: Don't you wan't to handle possible Exceptions, from Scanner, not getting an int?

Comment: No, that's up to OP to handle it. As this is a homework question it's better for OP to search for it and decide if he wants to handle it or not @userunknown

Answer (score -3):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FactMore {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=1;

        int factorial = factorial(n);   

        while (n >= 1) {
            System.out.print("Enter a non-negative integer (-1 to quit) : ");
            n = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (n == 0) {
                System.out.print(n = 1);
            } else if (n == -1) {
                System.out.print("Goodbye!"); 
            } else {
                factorial = factorial(n);
                System.out.println(n + "! = " + factorial);
            }
        }
    }

    public static int factorial(int n) {

        int factorial = 1;

        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            factorial = factorial * i; 
        }

        return factorial;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please let's avoid code-dump answers as they offer no help to future visitors to this site. The answer's explanation is usually much more important than the code.